npm create vite opens another terminal
When I write npm create vite@latest, it opens another terminal saying
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3447]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

I use VSCode, but the same thing happens in cmd. In VSCode, the original terminal has PS at the start, but the terminal that opens after npm create vite@latest doesn't.
It also happens when I try npx create-react-app my-app
In the tutorials I followed these commands made a new react app. I asked on Reddit and it's apparently a terminal thing. I haven't tried much because I don't understand the problem.
